# Can unittest's setUpClass classmethod return a value to be used throughout the other tests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, class

I'm attempting to write unit tests for a program that relies on module-level data(a JSON file).
So, I was thinking I would set up a test JSON file using the `setUpClass` classmethod and then tear it down after the tests have been run.
The issue I have is that the set up of the module-level JSON returns a value which is required by other functions of the program which I also intend to test.
Here is an example of what I mean:

```
import unittest
import myProg  

class TestProg(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # initialize() creates the JSON file
        myProg.initialize()
        f = myProg.initialize_storage()
        return f

    def test_prog_func(self):
        myProg.prog_func("test_key", "test_value", f)
```

`f` is the item which is required by the rest of my functions. *this code does not work*. I'm looking for a way to allow me to "`return f`" from the setUpClass to be used throughout the test.

Comment: setUpClass method's first argument `cls` is class variable. save in it. `cls.f = f`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't return anything, no, the return value is ignored. You can set *class attributes*, which are available to all tests:

```
class TestProg(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # initialize() creates the JSON file
        myProg.initialize()
        cls.f = myProg.initialize_storage()  # set a class attribute

    def test_prog_func(self):
        # self.f here will find the class attribute
        myProg.prog_func("test_key", "test_value", self.f)
```

That's because attribute lookups on the instance will also find class attributes (that's how methods are found, after all).

Note that the test runner will create a new instance of your class for each test being run; that ensures that the instance state is clean. The class state is not cleared, so if you *alter* your class attributes in a test you no longer will have proper test isolation.